# Android AlertDialog center title and list items

Tags: java, android, listview, android-alertdialog, title

I got a good idea for centering the text of AlertDialog Message from below link :

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/01/30/central-aligning-the-default-message-text-in-alertdialog-in-android/#comment-1802653

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("My Title");
builder.setMessage("CoderzHeavennHeaven of all working codes.");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();

TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

This works perfectly fine for message text.

If I try the same for the title, it's giving me null.
How do I do the same for title and whats id for it?

```
TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

If I add list items and try the same for list items, it's giving me null.
How do I do the same for list items and whats id for it?

```
String[] listAryVar = {"Edit", "Renam", Delete"};

builder.setItems(listAryVar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface DlgPsgVar, int which)
        {
            // |==| |* CodTdo *|
        }
    })

ListView messageText = (ListView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
messageText.getCount());
```

Try 2 : If I do as below, code runs but Text is still left aligned.

```
ListView dialogListView = dialog.getListView();

for(int i=0; i < dialogListView.getCount(); i++)
{
    TextView textView = (TextView)dialogListView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, dialogListView);;
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```

I know we use custom view and set that view. but I feel we can even change the built-in views. Because in android we can do anything.

Comment: create a layout for your dialog title (in which you can center the text for example), inflate it and give it to the builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with custom alert dialog

**custom_alert_dialog.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:padding="5dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="this is title"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="this is message"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your activity

```
 AlertDialog.Builder customAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    View viewDialog = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.custom_alert_dialog, null);
    customAlert.setView(viewDialog);

    TextView title = (TextView) viewDialog.findViewById(R.id.title);
TextView message = (TextView) viewDialog.findViewById(R.id.message);


title.setText("this is title");
message.setText("this is message");

    customAlert.create();
    customAlert.show();
```

You will get something like this

[image]

Comment: I know we use custom view and set that view. but I feel we can even change the built-in views. Because in android we can do anything.

Comment: Because you get your id message from generated file and he is read only it's alert_dialog.xml and that message id is Textview but title belong to com.android.internal.widget.DialogTitle so that's why your title is null cause it is not Textview,the best solution for you is to create custom alert dialog and you can do with him what ever you want.